# how can i change formik input value field whith redux state in react

Tags: reactjs, formik

i want change field value when  click in edit button actually when  click in button change value of input field
[image]

[image]

Comment: Providing code instead of images of code helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: please check my pics